# Beginner having trouble running Javascript on Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

New coder here. As the title suggests, I spent the past two hours trying to run a simple Javascript on VSC with no avail. Could someone help me set my sandbox up? Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Much appreciated!

kt

1. Downloaded VSC
2. Downloaded nodejs
3. Entered "node scriptname.js" in terminal
4. Error message above

Comment: Looks like you're putting that code in to a .js file. It needs to be in an .html file - or you can keep it in a .js file but you need to remove all the HTML from it.

Comment: you have written HTML in js file, either change file extension to .html and then open it in live server (VS Code Extension) or remove html and just write js code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific error is caused by you running `node` from the console and providing the wrong path to *test.js*.

You are in the Desktop directory and just specifying a file name, so Node is looking for *test.js* in the *Desktop* directory.

You have saved *test.js* in a directory called *Coding Practice*.

You need to either:

- `cd` to the correct directory *or*
- Provide the path to the directory as part of the second argument

Typically, when using VS Code, you would pick the *Open Folder* option from the *File* menu to work within your project's root directory (i.e. *Coding Practice*) which will provide you with a file list and do things like open the terminal in that directory by default.

---

Once you solve that problem you will run into your second problem.

The contents of *test.js* isn't JavaScript!

It's an HTML document with JavaScript embedded in it.

You need to:

- Give it a `.html` file extension *and*
- Open it using a web browser and **not** with Node.js (the traditional way to do that from within VS Code is with the [live server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) but you'll really want to have VS code open in the right directory (as above) for that.)

You can't even remove the HTML from the file and run it with Node.js because `alert` (the function you call) is a Web API and not core JavaScript nor a Node.js API.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!